# Is there a podspec for Opencv?

Tags: ios, objective-c, opencv, computer-vision, cocoapods

I have recently used Cocoapods - library dependency management tool in objective C. It has podspec for commonly used libraries like ZXing, AFNetworking etc. Have anyone come across **Opencv** podspec?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This issue is fixed. You can install OpenCV with CocoaPods. Take a look here: https://github.com/SebastienThiebaud/OpenCV-iOS/blob/master/README.md

Actually, the pod version number is wrong, the version 0.0.1 is OpenCV 2.4.3

Sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 3):

You can always use the search function. Using "pod search opencv" reveals that a podspec exits. The bad news is that it's a version 0.0.1...

Comment: When I use this version 0.0.1 it gives the following error

**ld: library not found for -lopencv2
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)**

Current version of OpenCV is 2.4.3. I don't know which version this pod supports.

Answer (score 0):

Add below in you Podfile and execute command 'pod install --no-repo-update'.

platform :ios, "7.0"

pod 'OpenCV', '2.4.9'